# How can I show excel file with addresses inside in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, import, excel

I have excel file with 1 column of address , city and country.
I want to "import" it into Google Earth and get placemarks of the addresses (2800 POI).
How can I do it ?

Comment: You need Google Earth Pro to do [this](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176685). But if you are able to geocode the addresses first, you should be able to use [this](http://www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx) without Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your Excel file into a Google Fusion Table, Geocode, then use the share option to create the KML.

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2562055?hl=en&topic=2573107&ctx=topic

Comment: After I load to Fusion Table , How I Geocode?

Comment: follow these steps https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1012281?hl=en.  Usually when you click on the tab "Map of Location it will ask you which colum to use for the Geocoding."